# futures used with actors in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor, future

I want to create a server/client system using akka remoting. At first I create a simple remote Server. (I wrote the code below for testing purposes and to clarify my concepts so it really doesn't do much.)

I want my client to send a username and a password to the server which the server can verify and reply back. At first I create a client actor. From my client object I send this actor the username and password (I use future here). The client actor then uses another future to send this username and password to the server.

The server in my code gets the username and password and prints it out. The problem is I dont get anything back from the server. Since I used a future to send the information to the server, it should reply back with a result. This is where I think I have a conceptual problem. Going through the akka documentation did not clarify this. But I an sure I am messing up something very basic. The server code is:

**EDITED after suggestions from TrustNoOne and cmbaxter.**

```
package server


import collection.mutable
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import shared._
import shared.CaseClass._

object Server extends App { 
val system = ActorSystem("ServerSystem",
     ConfigFactory.parseString("""
   akka {
     actor {
       provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
     }
     remote {
       netty.tcp {
         hostname = 127.0.0.1
         port = 5555
       }
     }
   }
 """))
system.actorOf(Props[ServerActorClass], "ServerActor")
}

class ServerActorClass extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case userPass: UserPass => {
      sender ! verified()
      println(userPass)
    }
    case testMsg: String => println("Got a msg"+ testMsg)
  }
}
```

The client code is:

```
package client

import ...

object Client extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("ClientSystem",
    ConfigFactory.parseString("""
   akka {
     actor {
       provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
     }
     remote {
       netty.tcp {
         hostname = 127.0.0.1
         port = 0
       }
     }
   }
  """))
  val clientActor = system.actorOf(Props[ClientActor], name = "ClientActor") //the local actor

  implicit val timout = Timeout(50 seconds)
  val f = ask(clientActor, UserPass("a","b"))
  f.onSuccess {
    case GO => println("Got something back from Client actor") //Still doesn't happen!
  }
}


class ClientActor extends Actor {

  // create the remote actor
  val server = context.actorFor("akka.tcp://ServerSystem@127.0.0.1:5555/user/ServerActor")

  implicit val timout = Timeout(1 seconds)

  def receive = {
    case a: String => println("back" + a)
    case a: UserPass => { 
      val f: Future[Any] = (server ? a) 
      f.onSuccess {
        case response: verified => {
          println("Got something back from server") //Does happen now!
          val asker = sender()
          asker ! GO()
        }
        case response: verificationFailed => {
           val asker = sender() 
           asker ! NO()
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Case classes that are shared by both the client and the server:

```
package shared
case object CaseClass {
  case class verified //Server msg to acknowledge user and pass successful verification
  case class verificationFailed //Server msg saying user pass verification failed
  case class GO
  case class NO
  case class UserPass(user:String, pass:String)
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong. If someone could explain rather than just point out the problem, it would be great, since I am looking to learn.

Comment: Have you tried adding different callbacks to your `Future` to try to print `onFailure` for example, see if anything wrong happens?

Comment: just tried. Nothing changes. Is this because futures do not act the same way with remote actors the way would with local ones? Is there any restriction like that?

Comment: If you use an `onComplete` instead of `onSuccess` as suggested by @vptheron, you should at the very least get a timeout `Failure` if you do not get a response within one second.  Also, `onSuccess` is a PartialFunction, so if it's not defined for the type of result returned, nothing happens.  Try adding a `case any => println(any)` into your `onSuccess` callback

Comment: It's impossible. If you put a callback on `onFailure` you'll at least see a timeout like @cmbaxter said.

Comment: vptheron, cmbaxter: You are right.I added the case any => println(any) to onSuccess callbacks of both the futures.I get back:

`class shared.CaseClass$verified$`

`[INFO] [04/29/2014 15:38:59.251] [ClientSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://ClientSystem/deadLetters] Message [shared.CaseClass$GO$] from Actor[akka://ClientSystem/user/ClientActor#1894492213] to Actor[akka://ClientSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.`

Comment: So you are seeing two issues described by @TrustNoOne.  First, you are getting back the type of class and not the instance of the class itself.  Second, you closed over the sender and thus got a deadletter.  Fix as described by TrustNoOne and you should be on the right track

Comment: @cmbaxter Could you please look at the last comment I made under TrustNoOne's answer?

Comment: @1xQ, can you update your code sample for `ClientActor` to include the change you made to prevent closing over the sender?

Comment: @cmbaxter I understood how this worked and was able to run the above program. Could you please tell me what difference there would be in above code if I wanted to pass an iterable object(like an ArrayBuffer which holds some information) from the server to the client instead of predefined case classes?

Comment: You should be able pass an Iterable object back to the client provided the items that are in that collection are able to be serialized by Akka Remoting.  Also, I would stay away from mutable collections like `ArrayBuffer` when sending responses from actors; stick to the immutable collections instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server actor, you're sending the response like this:

```
sender ! CaseClass.verified
```

You are actually sending the "verified" class **companion object** back to the client. You should either make the verified class a case object or send back to the client a verified **instance**:

```
sender ! CaseClass.verified()
```

You are doing other (unrelated) errors:

- closing over sender in the future callback (make a local alias `val replyTo = sender()`)
- not respecting naming conventions (capital letters, etc)
- using deprecated "actorFor". you have to use actorSelection (see akka docs)

Comment: "You cannot pattern match inside the future's onSuccess callback".  Wrong!  The `onSuccess` callback is simply a partial function taking a Any and returning Unit.  You can of course pattern match on it.

Comment: @cmbaxter Could you please elaborate?

Comment: it's closing over the sender in the ClientActor, in the pattern match that does not work.

Comment: just add case x => println(x.getClass) to the pattern match that doesn't work, and you'll see it prints the name of the "verified" class

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the closing over the sender.  I did not scroll down.  But your statement that you can not pattern match in `onSuccess` is completely wrong.

Comment: my bad, let me edit the answer... sorry (thanks for the removal of the downvote ;) )

Comment: @TrustNoOne You are right. Please take a look at the comment under the question.

Comment: You mean where you say you want to know what you're doing wrong? You basically are saying in the onSuccess "if the result is an instance of 'verified' do this, else if it's an instance of 'verificationFailed', then do that". The problem is that the response is an instance of the 'verified' class **companion object**, not an instance of the class. If "verified" is meant to be a singleton, you should declare it as a case object, and pattern match against it with `case verified => ...`

Answer (score 1):

You're exiting without waiting for a response.

```
implicit val timout = Timeout(50 seconds)
val f: Future[Any] = clientActor ? UserPass("s","a")
f.onSuccess {
  case GO => println("Got something back from Client actor") //Doesnt happen!
}
```

That sets up a *handler* for a callback, but then your program just exists.

Minimally, you could `scala.concurrent.Await.result(f)`

Comment: That's not the problem, he's not shutting down the actor system, his App never exits. The problem is that he is sending verified (the companion object) instead of verified() (an instance). Look at my answer

Comment: @RobStarling But wouldn't including `scala.concurrent.Await.result(f)` make the operation synchronous. I mean won't that become a blocking call?

Comment: @RobStarling tried to do what you suggested. However, I still receive the msg `dead letters encountered` when trying to send `GO()`. Could you please explain why `scala.concurrent.Await.result(f)` needs to be used? Is it to keep the actor alive until it receives the message? What do you think still causes the error to persist?

Comment: @1xQ yes, main would block. i only meant to say that you might need it to keep the program from exiting, but TrustNoOne pointed out that unless you shut down the actor system (which you should do), that's not the problem.